explicit tuple generic expansion
Simplified scenario (playground):
from typing import TypeVar, reveal_type

class A: ...
class B(A): ...
class C(A): ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)

def fun(*args: T) -> tuple[T, ...]: return args

# one parameter
reveal_type(fun(A()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.A, ...]"
reveal_type(fun(B()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.B, ...]"
reveal_type(fun(C()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.C, ...]"

# multiple parameters, same type
reveal_type(fun(A(), A()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.A, ...]"
reveal_type(fun(B(), B()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.B, ...]"
reveal_type(fun(C(), C()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.C, ...]"

# multiple parameters, different types
reveal_type(fun(A(), B()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.A, ...]"
reveal_type(fun(B(), C()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.A, ...]"
reveal_type(fun(C(), A()))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[gargs.A, ...]"

is there a way to annotate fun to teach mypy that fun should return tuple[A, B], tuple[B, C] and tuple[C, A] in the three latter cases?

as a workaround I could add a bunch of @overload functions definitions, one for each tuple type combination, but it's cumbersone at best

That's what TypeVarTuple is for:
(playground)
from typing import TypeVarTuple

Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')

def fun(*args: *Ts) -> tuple[*Ts]: return args

reveal_type(fun(A()))       # tuple[A]
reveal_type(fun(B()))       # tuple[B]
reveal_type(fun(C()))       # tuple[C]

reveal_type(fun(A(), A()))  # tuple[A, A]
reveal_type(fun(B(), B()))  # tuple[B, B]
reveal_type(fun(C(), C()))  # tuple[C, C]

reveal_type(fun(A(), B()))  # tuple[A, B]
reveal_type(fun(B(), C()))  # tuple[B, C]
reveal_type(fun(C(), A()))  # tuple[C, A]

TypeVarTuple cannot be bounded (yet), so we have to use some tricks:
(playground)
from typing import Any, Never, Protocol, TypeVar, TypeVarTuple

Fun = TypeVar('Fun')
Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')

class FunA(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, /, *args: A) -> Never: ...

def fun_decorator(fun: Fun) -> Fun | FunA:
    return fun

@fun_decorator
def fun(*args: *Ts) -> tuple[*Ts]: return args

reveal_type(fun(D()))            # error
reveal_type(fun(D(), A()))       # error
reveal_type(fun(C(), B(), D()))  # error

After being decorated, fun has the type of ((*Ts) -> tuple[*Ts]) | ((A, ...) -> Never). For the call to be type-safe, the arguments must satisfy both signatures. The signatures both accept a variadic number of arguments, but the latter requires that its arguments must all be of type A.
The return type is deduced to be tuple[*Ts] | Never, which is just tuple[*Ts] since Never has no member.

What's the purpose of the Never?

@DanielWalker So that tuple[*Ts] | Never equals to tuple[*Ts].

uhm... while the solution seems sound - I find issues with the real code; specifically my function is decorated with @asynccontextmanager, cfr https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=92fe1f8716f5dd225734035376610f80

main.py:11: error: Argument 1 to "asynccontextmanager" has incompatible type "Callable[[VarArg(*Ts)], AsyncIterator[tuple[*Ts]]]"; expected "Callable[[VarArg(Never), KwArg(Never)], AsyncIterator[Never]]"  [arg-type]

@VitoDeTullio I think this is a Mypy bug. Pyright outputs no errors for the same code.
